# ios ffmpeg with support for floating-point ABI

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg

How do I collect on ios ffmpeg with support for floating-point ABI?

I have an application that shows the video, but slow decoding.

ffmpeg compiled without support for floating-point ABI

```
./configure --prefix=armv7 --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe 
--disable-ffserver --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile 
--sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk" 
--target-os=darwin 
--cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" 
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard 
-miphoneos-version-min=6.1" --extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=1.0" 
--arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --enable-pic
```

I always get a warning

```
WARNING: Compiler does not indicate floating-point ABI, guessing soft.
```

I have tried

```
-mfloat-abi=hard
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a toolchain problem: which compiler is it using, `gcc` or `clang`? (Clang seems not to support the float-abi flag: http://www.google.com/search?q=clang+float-abi is full of woeful tales.)

Comment: I point gcc
--cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" 
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard

Comment: Ah. Hmm. Post more of the compilation log, I imagine some part of it may yield more information or at least some context.

Answer (score -1):

See this page for info about LGPL and iOS incompatibility, you need to think about this before attempting to use ffmpeg in an iOS app: [compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl](http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/). There are other options that are fully legal, and if you are doing h.264 encoding just using the built-in hardware is way way faster anyway.

Comment: project is done with ffmpeg I just transfer it to ios.
Now compatibility is not important, the result is important

Comment: Clearly you haven't heard that one can publish object files to be relinked with instead of distributing source code. LGPL 2.1 and iOS are COMPLETELY compatible.

Comment: Your definition of COMPLETELY is unlikely to match many other people's idea of what that word means. Even if linking issues were not a problem, iOS already provides hardware h.264 decoding and it is significantly faster than ffmpeg's software based approach.

Comment: IANAL, but my lawyers were happy with LGPL and iOS. Anyway, who said they're only using ffmpeg for h.264 decoding?